# HttpURLConnection urlc

Tags: android, http, url

In my app, when the app is first started, during my splash screen, I am checking for network connectivity. If network connectiivty is present, I am moving into internet connectivity by calling the method below.

However,on purpose, I am manually disabling my internet connection (I am connected to router, but cannot enter webpages on my browser), yet the method below is always returning me -200- that is TRUE for internet connectivity.

```
public boolean hasActiveInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlc.setReadTimeout(4000);
        urlc.connect();
        Log.i("Splash", Integer.toString(urlc.getResponseCode()));
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it is the router that responding to your request. Anyways, why don't you go and look what's being sent as the response?

Comment: PCoder, here is the response i am getting from pinging google.com when I disable internet connectivity.

    C:\Windows\System32>ping google.com ---


    Pinging google.com [198.18.1.9] with 32 bytes of data:---
    Reply from 192.168.1.254: Destination host unreachable.---


    Ping statistics for 198.18.1.9:---
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Answer (score 1):

Try to include this code before openConnection()

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check internet connection :

```
    public boolean isInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You need to add manifest permission for this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Vishal Vijay, this checks for network connectivity and not internet. This will return true, if you are connected to a router, wifi, even though there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: more than 3.2 million times. probably 3.21 or 3.22. unsure.